# Crystal Report Problems when adding Line object

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Report sometimes I need to use a field with Can Grow property set to true but when I add line object to separate the rows for better readability the line doesn't adjust with the field growth and it intersects with the text. How to make the line adjust itself with the field growth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a lot of try and error I found this option which fulfill that requirement (for CR under Visual Studio):
Right click the line, select Format Object, then check the option: Move to Bottom of Section when printing.